# jqGrid Caption bar Closed by Default

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid and it has a caption on it. When I click button grid hides and just caption bar remains. When I load the page I want my table is hided by default(however I should see the caption bar) How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option for it:

```
hiddengrid: true
```